# can we change android PDFTRON tools icons?

Tags: android, pdf, pdftron

I am using PDFTRON SDK in my android application. is there any way to change tools icons? also can we replace our own tools with PDFTRON tools ( I'm not talking about all tools, I am talking about some tools)
I have read official documentation of PDFTRON many times. i found enabling or disabling tools, but didn't find changing/customizing icons.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a project demonstrating how to change colors of each components of the app:
https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-android-samples/tree/master/CustomUI

For icons, you can create an vector drawable in your application with the same name resource in tools to replace the icon. For example, say you need a different line annotation icon, you will create a vector drawable with name "ic_annotation_line_black_24dp" placed in your application. This will replace the default one in the library.